# MissingPropertyException: Gradle Task Fails Due to Unknown Property

Tags: java, gradle

I am encountering the following error:

```
    Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'integrationTest' for SourceSet container of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSetContainer.
```

This is my `build.gradle` file. I have a `integrationTest` task defined already.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.8'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
}

group = 'com.app.api'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.11.0'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
}

tasks.register('integrationTest', Test) {
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
}

tasks.withType(Jar).configureEach {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE

    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = 'com.app.api.ApiApplication'
    }

    configurations["compileClasspath"].each { file ->
        from(zipTree(file.absoluteFile))
    }
}
```

How can one make `integrationTest` property be known to gradle?

Answer (score 1):

Using the `ext` block (which allows you to define custom properties and methods that can be accessed from anywhere in your build file), I can add the custom property `integrationTest`

```java
ext {
    integrationTest = project.hasProperty('integrationTest')
}
```

And I added a check in the `integrationTest` task:

```java
tasks.register('integrationTest', Test) {
    if (integrationTest) {
        testClassesDirs = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDirs
        classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
    }
}
```

Now when I add the system property via the terminal:
`./gradlew integrationTest DintegrationTest=true`

The property's value will be set to `true`.